# How to find the largest cliques in a graph in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

The largest cliques mean it has the largest size.
Came across `from networkx.algorithms.clique import find_cliques` but I do not know how to use it.
It takes in only one parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph(graph)
max(nx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques(G), key = len)

#[8, 0, 9, 10]
```

Comment: May I know is this solution the fastest way of doing it? What is the complexity for this solution? And is there another way to do it?

Comment: @newbie-here Find the maximum (largest) clique is really expensive so that's the heaviest part. The algorithm implemented in `networkx` is O(3^(n/3)) for an n-vertex graph, which is "ok" since finding the maximum clique is an NP problem

Comment: @newbie-here Also there's a lot of papers about it you can check. Search for "maximum clique" or "maximum clique problem"

Comment: understood, thank you! will read up more on it!

Comment: @newbie-here I'm happy to help! :)